# Using Python Selenium how to close the current tab which got opened when clicked a legal link on webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is on a webpage i am testing it has a link called "legal" when  clicked will  open a new tab  where all the different pages links are available. once i am done working with that  links have to close that tab  and move to main  tab where legal link was there.
I tried 
`driver.close()` it did not work.it is not closing the tab

Can anyone please help me  how to close the correct tab and move to primary one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by using `window_handels` and `switch_to.window()`.

so before you click on "legal" button, store the current window handle by

```
parent_handle  = driver.window_handles[0]
```

after clicking the 'legal' button, you switch to new child handle

```
child_handle= [x for x in driver.window_handles if x != parent_handle][0]
driver.switch_to.window(child_handle)
```

then add a sleep for a few seconds and do your work. then you can close the tab by

```
driver.close()
```

and now if want you can move to parent/previous website

```
driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Reference:-

https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903

```
1)Open a new window/tab by simulating a click on a link
2)Add a focus on this new tab
3)Wait for an element on the new page to be rendered (ui.WebDriverWait)
4)Do whatever you have to do on this new page
5)Close the tab
6)Return focus on original window opener
```